# Is there any benefit to a property returning a member of another class instead of setting the property in the constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, properties

My question relates specifically to the benefit (or opposite) of initializing a property with some value from another class over simply having the property `get` the value.

For example, does this implementation:

```
public class Foo
{
    public object Bar { get; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = OtherClass.Bar;
    }
}
```

have any actual advantage over this implementation:

```
public class Foo
{
    public object Bar { get => OtherClass.Bar; }
}
```

I ask because the second implementation, in my opinion, is easier to read and obviously more concise but I don't know if there are any measurable differences between the two besides line count.

The only similar question I could find is [C# Is there any benefit to assigning class properties in the class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001987) and this does not answer my question.

Comment: In the first example the value of Bar is initialized once, and is then never changed.  In the second example, each time you query Bar it will requery the value in OtherClass.Bar, so if that has changed then you will return a different value.

Comment: Even if `OtherClass.Bar` is readonly there is an important distinction why I'd avoid choosing the second option: you are creating a reference to `OtherClass` which can keep alive an object that maybe could and should be collected by the GC.

Comment: @InBetween In the code shown `OtherClass` has to be a class, so `Bar` is a static member.  Nothing is being kept alive in one and not the other.

Comment: @Servy yes I agree, if the other class is static. Although the naming convention and shown code seems to imply it is, its not a fact, Thats why I state that it *might* keep alive something that it shouldn't. Its simply something he should consider.

Comment: @InBetween It's not about naming convention, it's about the fact that there is no variable `OtherClass` that's in scope.  Since there is no variable called `OtherClass`, the only way it would compile is if it's a static class.

Comment: @Servy thats why I added "shown code", you might have missed it, I edited the commentary straight away. Anyhow I've got the impresion you are splitting hairs here, I'm not sure to what purpose. My commentary simply states that this can keep alive things that shouldn't be kept alive. If its static, then this is not an issue, if its not, then it could be. Although the shown code is static, its not specified anywhere in the question so it could simply be a bad example by the OP. Pointing out a potential issue is added value, but I guess you see it otherwise.

Comment: @Servy in my specific implementation I am using a singleton but I didn't want to focus the question on Singleton/Static instances which is why I didn't write `OtherClass.Instance.Bar`. It was just supposed to be more of a PsuedoCode demonstration regardless of the origin of the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences. The get-only property (A) does the following:

1. Copy the value/reference at the time the constructor is called.
2. Retain that value/reference.
3. This means that Foo will continue to refer to a snapshot of that property's value at construction time.
4. This also means that OtherClass will not be kept alive by Foo.

Whereas the lambda property is doing the following (B):

1. Dereference OtherClass when called, and return the current value of bar.
2. This means that OtherClass will be kept alive.
3. It also means that OtherClass can be changed, changing all the values of the properties that refer to it without needing to re-set them (or make them readonly).
4. Lastly, and most importantly, it means that the value of the property can change (i.e. the reference / value of Bar).

In terms of the differences, use A when you want a read-only snapshot of a value, and use B when you want a live value that can change.

Comment: (A): How does Foo not keep OtherClass alive? `OtherClass.Bar` is a reference to an object, that reference is copied to `Foo.Bar`. Can OtherClass fall out of scope without destroying the object referenced by both `OtherClass.Bar` and `Foo.Bar`?

Comment: OtherClass can be collected, because it isn't referenced, but the reference to Bar will be kept alive.

Answer (score 2):

The two implementations are not the same:

- The first implementation "freezes" the value of `OtherClass.Bar` as of the time the constructor of `Foo` is called. Should `OtherClass.Bar` change later, the users of `Foo.Bar` would not see it.
- The second implementation will give you the current object from `OtherClass.Bar` each time you get `Foo.Bar` property.

Once you decide which behavior you wish to have, only one of the two choices remain.

**Note:** C# 6 lets you rewrite the second example as follows:

```
public object Bar => OtherClass.Bar;
```

Comment: Just to be clear on the first implementation: Because Bar is an object it is generally a reference type. So, I would still see changes from OtherClass.Bar in this.Bar (such as Bar.someNum).

The reference wouldn't update though, so if the underlying object at OtherClass.Bar changed that wouldn't be reflected in this.Bar...right?

Comment: @MissingL_tter Right, changes in the original `Bar` object would continue being visible; only replacements of `Bar` with a different object would not have any effect on `Foo.Bar`.